# Write to new lines of sequential file in Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, file-writing

Okay, so, I'm supposed to be able to access a file that already has values in it and write values to that file (namely questions).

This is my code so far:

```
Private Sub AddQuestion(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnQuestions.Click
    Dim pass, response, question As String
    pass = "sample01"
    response = InputBox("Please enter the administrator password.", "Password")
    If response = pass Then
        FileOpen(1, "W:\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Culminating\assets\questions.txt", OpenMode.Output)
        Do
            question = InputBox("Enter new question.", "New Question")
            If question = String.Empty Then
                Exit Do
            End If
            Write(1, question)
            WriteLine(1)
        Loop
        FileClose(1)
    Else : MsgBox("Incorrect password. Please enter again.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Incorrect Password")
    End If
End Sub
```

This adds the questions to my file, however, if I exit out of the input box and try again, it will overwrite the old questions with the new ones.

Comment: The FileOpen function is a very old function, provided primarily for backwards compatibility with VB 6. If you are writing new code in VB.NET (or, as it seems, *learning* VB.NET), then you should consider doing this the modern way. That would either be using the VB.NET-specific `My.Computer.FileSystem` object to do file I/O, or the general .NET `System.IO.File` class.

Comment: @CodyGray thank you. I would like to do it this way, however our teacher has specific requirements for how we write this code so I'm trying to do it the way he has demonstrated it to us.

Comment: Maybe provide you teacher's specific requirements so that someone can provide an answer that meets those requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FileOpen(1, "W:\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Culminating\assets\questions.txt", OpenMode.Output)
```

`OpenMode.Output` opens the file for overwriting the contents. You want `OpenMode.Append`.

Comment: Ah, our notes said to use `OpenMode.Output` so I went along with that. Thank you very much, worked perfectly.